# Dart/flutter isolate/future as worker

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, backgroundworker

I made a small game using C# and Xamarin a while ago. In the game (it's something like chess) I have an algorithm which calculates the turn for the computer. It's quite a heavy task (takes up to 20 secs to complete), and for the UI not to freeze I used a background worker, where I pass through the table and a few other variables.

Now I'm trying to remake the game in Dart and Flutter. I tried to find the equivalent of threading, and found isolates. But beeing an isolate I can't seem to be able to pass through a 2D array (the table), as it is too big (I assume), and crashes the whole VM. Is this achievable in any way?

Comment: How big is the table you want to pass?

Comment: My personal recommendation would be if it takes 20 seconds to calculate the computer's turn, that process is in dire need of optimizing. I don't know many people who would be willing to sit around that long after taking their turn waiting for the computer to figure out theirs. (Playing against another human is a different story, as you get to watch them squirm in the meantime.)

Comment: But I digress. Can you post some code showing how you are trying to do this and a sample of what data you are trying to pass? Are you getting an error message and, if so, could you post that as well?

Comment: @Abion47 well, I tried that part, but even if it would only take 2-3 seconds, the UI still would freeze if I am correct, so that's not really a solution.

Comment: I didn't offer a solution. I asked if you could post code showing what you're trying to do. It's hard to provide a solution to your problem if you don't show what the problem is. And Christian brings up a good point too - how big is this table exactly if it's too big to pass to the other isolate?

Comment: @Abion47 Sorry for my previous comment. 
To be honest, the question is more about how the language works in general, as I am not really familiar with it. (Nor with the whole concept of async and await)
I don't really understand if and when I need to use an isolate or a future. Will the app UI freeze if I use a future? Or is an isolate just a way to use the multicore capabilities of the device?
I hope the question is better formulated and answerable this way. And thank you for your answers.

Comment: Futures don't run at the same time as your UI code but they do run on the same thread, so if your async code takes too much time it will freeze the UI. Isolates are Dart's way of multithreading but it's a bit different as each isolate is a completely separate process (rather than thread) and as such the main "thread" can't directly share data with the isolates. The two are very distinct mechanisms and shouldn't ever be confused as they aren't interchangeable, but it can be a bit unclear to someone who doesn't understand the difference between them. (Google "asynchronous vs parallel".)

Comment: I am still a bit confused: in this example [flutter http request](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) a future is used to make an http request. Why doesn't the UI freeze if the response takes a long time? Or do they assume it won't?

Comment: My thought is, that if the http request takes a long time, then it is just the same (in that regard) as if it was my algorithm running there. Is that true?